# Azure DevOps Create WorkItem HTML field issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell, rest, azure-devops

I chained a few programs together to give end users the ability to create workItems in Azure Devops (ADO) from an outside service. I am linking a Service Management form (CA Service Catalog) to a node.js API which runs a powershell module (using the node-powershell module) to create a workitem in ADO. While it has had its bumps, it mostly functions as designed. The issue I am running into is specifically where the workItem fields take HTML. If a user keeps the description simple, it will process just fine...however I can't expect that to be the case. Users will copy/paste from other docs, include all sorts of special characters, etc. The tricky piece is that the description string is changing hands so many times that things are getting jumbled and the errors put out by ADO are not really helpful. Mostly `{"name":"PS_CMD_FAIL_ERROR"}` and `{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"You must pass a valid patch document in the body of the request.", "typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssPropertyValidationException,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common","typeKey":"VssPropertyValidationException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}`. Which just tells me that it doesn't like a field. If I replace the description with a tiny string and send it through again then it works. I notice when doing a GET request on an existing work item created directly in ADO that the description consist of HTML and not just a string.

Things Ive tried:

1. adding `<pre>, <div> and <body>` tags before and after description string in the initial form script before it heads out to node.
2. using regex to replace things that I feel may have an impact such as \n \t \r. I initially got over another hump when I realized that powershell couldn't comprehend those.
3. using new DomParser() to convert string to HTML, but all i saw in the console was a body tag added to front and back.

Essentially all Im looking for is a way to take the input string from the initial form and make an exact "quote" of it in the workItem description, regardless of the contents of the description string. Below is a snippet of code from two places: the function in node that is passing arguments and invoking the PS module...and the PATCH request contained within the module. Im pretty well versed in JS, but this is my first foray into powershell and it does not feel like a lateral move. I feel like it must be something relatively simple with ' vs " or adding tags on at some point. Perhaps something to be done with the $Description variable when PS reads it to make the request? Anything helps.

```
let createItem=(cb,req,res)=>{
  console.log('hitting ADO createItem', req);
  ps.addCommand(`Import-Module "C:\\pathtomodule\\CreateWorkItem.psm1" -Force`)
  ps.addCommand(`CreateFeature -Title "${req.title}" -Description "${req.description}" -AcceptanceCriteria "${req.acceptanceCriteria}" -BusinessValue "${req.businessValue}" -TimeCriticality "${req.timeCriticality}" -RROE "${req.rroe}" -Email "${req.email}" -TargetDate "${req.targetDate}" -ParentId "${req.parentId}" -ParentPath "${req.parentPath}"`)
  ps.invoke()
  .then(output => {
    console.log('pshell output',output)
    res.status(200).send(output);
    // ps.dispose().then(code => {console.log('successful dispose', code)}).catch(error => {console.log('dispose error', error)});
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('pshell error',err);
    res.status(500).send(err)
  });
};
```

```
Function CreateFeature {
Param ($Title, $Description, $AcceptanceCriteria, $BusinessValue, $TimeCriticality, $RROE, $Email, $TargetDate, $ParentId, $ParentPath)

**Token info declared here, removed for security**

Write-Host "Description test"
Write-Host $Description

$RestParams = @{
    Uri = "https://dev.azure.com/myorganization/_apis/wit/workitems/`$Feature?api-version=5.1&expand=relations"
    ContentType = 'application/json-patch+json'
    Headers = @{
        Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $token)
    }
    Method = "Patch"
    Body   = @(
        @{
            op    = "add"
            path  = "/fields/System.AreaPath"
            value = $ParentPath
        }
        @{
            op    = "add"
            path  = "/fields/System.Title"
            value = $Title
        }
        @{
            op    = "add"
            path  = "/fields/System.Description"
            value = $Description
        }
        @{
            op    = "add"
            path  = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria"
            value = $AcceptanceCriteria
        }
        @{
            op    = "add"
            path  = "/fields/Custom.RROE"
            value = $RROE
        }
        @{
            op    = "add"
            path  = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.TimeCriticality"
            value = $TimeCriticality
        }
        @{
            op    = "add"
            path  = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BusinessValue"
            value = $BusinessValue
        }
        @{
            op    = "add"
            path  = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.TargetDate"
            value = $TargetDate
        }
        @{
            op    = "add"
            path  = "/fields/Agile-SingleProject.RequestedBy"
            value = $Email
        }
        @{
            op = "add"
            path = "/relations/-"
            value = @{
            rel = "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse"
            url = "https://dev.azure.com/myorganization/_apis/wit/workItems/$ParentId"
            }
            }
            ) | ConvertTo-Json
}
```

Sample description that fails. It appears to be a copy/paste and includes formatting such as tabs that arent possible in the input field on the form.

```
The Attunity servers are outdated and need to be replaced. We need more memory and we can't order more for the version of server we are on.  We looked into using VMs but the CPU core count for Attunity is 32 and VMs are not big enough to give us 32 cores with out using the entire VM host, at which point we might as well buy our own server.  https://myorganization/_workitems/edit/workitemnumber

2 Servers
    Windows (x86 Physical)  2 x 16 cores @ 2.8 GHz (2 x 480GB drives plus 14 empty drive bays)  192GB Ram   1.92TB SS
1 Server
         Windows (x86 Physical) 2 x 16 cores @ 2.8 GHz (2 x 480GB drives plus 14 empty drive bays)  192GB Ram   1.92TB SS
```

Comment: can you give an example to the Description value?

Comment: Done, there is a sample at the bottom